# Exception in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 3.0.0 and I got this exception. Can anyone help me?

Thank you..

```
SEVERE: stack corruption. Is class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner instrumented for javaflow?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stack corruption. Is class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner instrumented for javaflow?
    at org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.StackRecorder.execute(StackRecorder.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.continueWith(Continuation.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:129)
    at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.start(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:610)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:344)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:346)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:305)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1382)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:692)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:879)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:801)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:419)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.raporyeni.BeyannameGoruntule.runPDFReport(BeyannameGoruntule.java:169)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.raporyeni.BeyannameGoruntule.beyannameGoruntule(BeyannameGoruntule.java:71)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.web.DispatchServlet.beyannameGoruntule(DispatchServlet.java:601)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.web.DispatchServlet.goruntuleme(DispatchServlet.java:425)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.web.DispatchServlet.doRequestProcessing(DispatchServlet.java:275)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.web.DispatchServlet.doPost(DispatchServlet.java:527)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.ebyn.merkezislemleri.web.DispatchServlet.doGet(DispatchServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at tr.gov.ggm.vedop2.eyeks.servlet.EyeksMainFilter.doFilter(EyeksMainFilter.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:870)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

Javaflow continuations subreport runner need a different JasperReport jar, called jasperreports-javaflow-x.y.z.jar, which has bytecode instrumentation required by Javaflow added to JR classes.  You will have to manually add this jar to your local repository.

The link to download the jar is http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/

Please make sure that the iReport version, the jasperReport jar version and the jar version for workflow is same otherwise you will land up in different trouble.

This error is basically related to the threading of the sub report on an app server env. If the jars do not solve the problem, then property file will need to be edited to point to the threaded version of the subreport runner.

This link will be very useful:

http://jasonkratz.com/2008/07/29/running-jasperreports-with-subreports-in-an-app-server-environment/